# PyQt4: AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlineedit

I have a QLineEdit, and I want to set a placeholder text. When I call `setPlaceholderText(string)` I get an AttributeError, but:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
'4.7.4'
>>> QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
'4.7.0'
```

and from the QAssistant:

> This property holds the line edit's
>   placeholder text.
>   ...
>   This property was introduced in Qt 4.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that although the libraries are very recent, the bindings are simply not that up to date.

You might want to check out [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) - a Nokia project with (IMO) fewer license issues than PyQt.