# 'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I know that [this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952850/pyqt4-attributeerror-qlineedit-object-has-no-attribute-setplaceholdertext), but there only `PySide` was referred as alternative. I kind of want it to work using `PyQt4`.

The problem is simple: I am using QtDesigner to create a `.ui` file. In the QtDesigner preview the `PlaceholderText` in my `QTextEdit` works just fine. In my `python` program however I get this error:

```
'QTextEdit' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'
```

which is not true, at least according to the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#placeholderText-prop). The feature was added in version `5.2` and I am using `5.6`. `PyQt4`s version is `4.11.4` (up to date). My `python` version is `3.4`. Any idea why it is not working?

Edit: I am open to alternatives involving using another object instead of `QTextEdit`, but I do not want to switch to `PySide`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyQt4 you are using has not been [built against Qt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt_v5.html), so it cannot access any of the features added in Qt5.